# 500 Error, Get custom field and returning it

Tags: php, functions, 500-internal-error

I am using this code but getting a 500 error on the `IF` part. Not sure why this happens.

```
$instac = get_the_author_meta( 'au-instagram', $current_author->ID );
if (!empty($instac)) {
    return '<a href="' . $instac . '" class="kalim">instagram</a>'
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon: `instagram</a>'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 error or internal server error is probably caused by a PHP error.
By enabling WordPress debug, you’ll easily find where the problem is.
You can follow the instructions here https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log

From your code, it’s easy, you’re missing a semi-column before the closing curly bracket.